# Comando "global" en stata usarlo en python

Tags: python, numpy, stata

Tengo el siguiente código en stata:

```
global phillips_eq_us "(pcecoreus_gap F.pcecoreus_gap  un_gap)"
```

donde lo que está en paréntesis son las variables que son parte de una ecuación que será usada para un 3sls posteriormente.
Para llevarlo a python realicé el siguiente código:

```
df['phillips_eq_us'] = np.array(df['pcecoreus_gap'] + df['F.pcecoreus_gap'] + df['un_gap'])
df['is_eq_us'] = np.array(df['ygap_fred'] + df['fedfund'] + df['F.pcecoreus_gap'] + df['F.ygap_fred'])
df['taylor_eq_us'] = np.array(df['fedfund'] + df['pcecoreus_gap'] + df['ygap_fred'])
df['okun_eq_us'] = np.array(df['un_gap'] + df['ygap_fred'])
```

Pero no me convence el hecho de estar sumando, porque estaría creando una variable nueva con los valores sumados de las otras. Lo intenté haciéndolo sin matrices, pero es el mismo problema.
Mi idea es que, por ejemplo, `df['phillips_eq_us']`sea la variable que contenga las otras tres que están dentro. Espero se entienda y esperaré sus respetuosas respuestas.

Edit1:

Aquí es donde uso el global en stata, para el 3sls

```
reg3  $phillips_eq_us $is_eq_us $taylor_eq_us $okun_eq_us  ///
```

Y lo siguiente es la forma en que está hecho en stata lo que se usa en el código anterior

```
global phillips_eq_us "(pcecoreus_gap F.pcecoreus_gap  un_gap)"
global is_eq_us "(ygap_fred fedfund F.pcecoreus_gap F.ygap_fred, noconstant)"
global taylor_eq_us "(fedfund  pcecoreus_gap ygap_fred)"
global okun_eq_us "(un_gap ygap_fred )"
```

Noten que en la segunda línea agrega el término "noconstant", el que no he logrado agregar.

Edit2:
Esto hice en python, lo trabajé como un diccionario:

```
phillips_eq_us = dict(covariates=(df['F.pcecoreus_gap'], df['un_gap'], df['pcecoreus_gap']))
is_eq_us = dict(covariates=(df['ygap_fred'], df['fedfund'], df['F.pcecoreus_gap'], df['F.ygap_fred']))
taylor_eq_us = dict(covariates=(df['fedfund'], df['pcecoreus_gap'], df['ygap_fred']))
okun_eq_us = dict(covariates=(df['un_gap'], df['ygap_fred']))
```

Comment: ¿Cómo se supone que se fusionan las tres variables en `df['phillips_eq_us']`: producto, añadir filas, añadir columnas,....?¿Qué _"forma"_ tiene `df`? En _stata_, `global` es un macro para no tener que escribir el mismo código varias veces. No tiene ningún sentido verlo sin saber dónde se aplica.

Comment: Es que la idea es hacer lo mismo que se hace con global de stata en python. No es el fin el fusionar las variables, de ninguna manera, lo hice así porque fue lo unico que se me ocurrió en el momento, y lo subí porque en otras preguntas me piden que suba lo que he intentado.

Comment: También se suele pedir que se ponga el resultado esperado. No sé cómo usas el `global` en stata. Si pones un ejemplo tal vez entendamos qué esperas que haga python.

Comment: @ChemaCortes Ahí agregué dos Edit para que los puedas revisar porfa, gracias!

Comment: A ver si lo entiendo. ¿Te vale algo así? `phillips_eq_us = df[['pcecoreus_gap', 'F.pcecoreus_gap', 'un_gap']]`

Comment: Nono, no es con df, es con dict y todo lo que sale en la última parte del edit